# Can I see uncommited changes in the H2 console?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, h2, transactional

I am using an H2 database for Testing. Of course tests get rolled back every time they changes some of the data. This is why I cannot see the changes inside of my H2 console. Can I somehow change this, so that I can see temporary changes in the H2 console?

Example:

- I have the table USERS and my `data.sql` script creates 5 entires in
  it.
- I let run a Test with `@Transactional` annotation, that deletes one
  of the USERS.
- I have a breakpoint inside the test, after the
  deletion.
- I reach it, log into the H2 console and still see 5
  entries.

I'd like to see only 4. After the test is finished, it should be 5 again so that it does not affect other tests... I could see 2 possible ways:

- Remove the `@Transactional` annotation and install another mechanism that re-arranges the data. Do some real commits inside of the tests.
- Somehow see these uncommited changes inside of the H2 console. I dont know if there is any framework or something that could help me here..?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and set the isolation level:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
```

Keep in mind that isolation config is only designed to work with `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW or REQUIRED`